# Service stopping another Service

Tags: android

i have a question about Services in Android.
I have a application with two Services A and B.
Is it possible that Service A can stop Service B?
I dont want to do it through a Activity, cause the Application will be in Background. If some special Event happen in Service A, then it should tell Service B to stop. How can i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need some other way to obtain an object of SeriviceA but this is the basic idea. Services are Contexts just like Activities are.

```
stopService(new Intent(ServiceA.this, ServiceB.class));
```

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than i thought :) It works. Inside Service A i can stop now Service B.